# Update fields in previously saved documents using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an old schema that I want to update. After updating the schema, the previous records saved before the new schema do not reflect the new fields I specified on the new schema. How do I make them reflect all the fields on the new schema.
I tried using `mongoose defaults` but it didn't work.
Here's my code

```
const user = mongoose.Schema({
  _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  email : String,
  firstname : String,
  lastname : String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', user)
```

I want to add `age` field (and it should appear on all previous documents). Currently, only new documents reflect the `age` field. How do I do that? Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, mongoose schemas are on write, So `default` help you on write, if in new insertion doc, if you've not send `age` field then mongoose will write the doc to DB including `age` field with default value in schema. But if you wanted to have that age field either you've to update all old docs with a default value or you can write query to do that, How are you querying, Can you give us ur query code?

Answer (score 3):

You can just run an `updateMany` command and filter out all the `User's` that don't have the `age` field, and then add the `age` field with a value of `undefined`:

```
User.updateMany({ age: { $exists: false} }, { $set: { age: undefined } });
```

Instead of doing that through `mongoose`, you could also just drop down into the DB and do it through the `mongo` shell like so:

```
db.users.updateMany({ age: { $exists: false} }, { $set: { age: undefined } });
```

Here's a gif of what that looks like:

[image: users db query]

Comment: Will setting the value to undefined change to whatever it should be if the user updates his/her info? 

For example, I am adding a field of  avatar which is a string that fetches the gravatar image of the email used in registering, how does that update if I do what you specified

Comment: @saas_joel I'm not sure I understand your question. In this example, I'm merely adding a field to all the `users` that don't have the field and then setting that field to `undefined`. This example wasn't for updating a single user, it was for updating all users and adding a new field to them if it didn't exist. Is that your use case?

Comment: Yeah, I get that now.
My use case was Gravatar specific, although what you specified above did come in handy.
Thanks